# Failed to start dbus.serviuce and dbus.socket

Tags: systemd, dbus, debian-bookworm

I have a Debian Bokworm Server which was migrated from bare metal to a Proxmox VM and then single services lock docker were migrated to their own VMs. I uninstalled for example all the docker content and cockpit.project.

The server is up and running but there are errors in syslog and I want to resolve them.

```
# systemctl --failed
UNIT         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
dbus.service loaded failed failed D-Bus System Message Bus
dbus.socket  loaded failed failed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket
```

```
# systemctl status dbus
× dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-11-14 18:45:11 CET; 1min 7s ago
TriggeredBy: × dbus.socket
       Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
    Process: 7445 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation >
   Main PID: 7445 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 3ms

Nov 14 18:45:11 hostname systemd[1]: Starting dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus...
Nov 14 18:45:11 hostname dbus-daemon[7445]: /usr/bin/dbus-daemon: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: version `LIBD>
Nov 14 18:45:11 hostname systemd[1]: dbus.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 14 18:45:11 hostname systemd[1]: dbus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 14 18:45:11 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus.
Nov 14 18:45:11 hostname systemd[1]: dbus.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 14 18:45:11 hostname systemd[1]: dbus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 14 18:45:11 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus.
```

What I tried:

- `apt install -f`
- `dpkg --configure -a`
- `apt remove dbus libdbus-1-3 && apt install dbus libdbus-1-3`
- `cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and checked all Symlinks, they are ok.
- Many reboots

Please help. I don't know whats wrong with this machine.

Comment: Your status output shows half of an error message (likely indicating a library mismatch). What does the rest of it say – and what does the symlink actually point to?